# What is a better implementation of this method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def search_and_sort (words, num)
 words.map{|a| a if  a.split("").sort.join == num.split("").sort.join}.compact
 end

def combine_anagrams(words)
  words.map{|a|  search_and_sort(words, a)}.uniq
end

p combine_anagrams(['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four', 'scar', 'creams', 'scream'] )

#==>[["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["for"], ["potatoes"], ["four"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

Comment: Simple "please improve my code"-type posts with no underlying question are more appropriate for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method from Enumerable:

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
  words.group_by do |word|
    word.chars.sort.join
  end.values
end
```

This method makes it very easy to group things by arbitrary criteria.

Comment: +1. I'd write it `words.group_by{|w| w.chars.sort.join}.values` but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @MarkThomas I try to avoid one-liners unless it's strictly necessary. Much easier to audit in a code review.

Comment: @tadman I disagree. The `end.values` doesn't read well. I prefer bracket-form blocks when chaining methods. The [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax) agrees with me. :)

Comment: That's just a series of opinions, many good, some questionable, which is why it gets forked fairly often. `end.values` might seem odd, but so does `}.values` to someone with a C background. Some stuff in Ruby is simply odd by definition, but you get used to it.